# Doctrine2 - Annotations: eager load (join) vs. nullable column (ManyToOne)

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, entity, nullable, eager-loading

I have this:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="TblCity",fetch="EAGER",cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="tblCity",referencedColumnName="Id")
 */
```

and it creates the correct JOIN for table tblCity in sql and TblCity entity is plugged in my parent entity - aka "Eager-Load"

Pseudo result:

```
PersonEntity: {
    Id: 1
    ...
    CityEntity: {
        Id: 1
        ...
    }
}
```

but, this ***column NEEDS to be nullable***

(if it runs into a "missing" foreign id it complains about missing proxy files for TblCity).

So it has to look like this:

```
/**
 * @Column(nullable=true)
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="TblCity",fetch="EAGER",cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="tblCity",referencedColumnName="Id")
 */
```

and *poff* there goes the "Eager-Load"

**The generated sql is missing the JOIN of table tblCity and the column contains only the id and not the entity for TblCity**

Pseudo result:

```
PersonEntity: {
    Id: 1
    ...
    CityEntity: 1 (as integer)
}
```

---

**What am I doing wrong?**

PS: I *CAN'T* use createQuery or such things, so please no solutions involving that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doctrine `@JoinColumn` annotation has an optiobal attribute `nullable` which defaults to `true`. Read more on this here in the documentation: **[21.2.15. @JoinColumn](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn)**

So the proper way to declare `nullable` for the join column is:

```
@JoinColumn(name="tblCity",referencedColumnName="Id", nullable=true)
```

But nullable is true by default so you **don't** really need it...

My guess would be that your `@Column` annotation is overruling the whole `@ManyToOne` annotation in your case. That is why you get only an `id` and no `TblCity` entity.